# PDE Junit Runner missing?

Tags: junit, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm developing a plugin in Eclipse, and wanted to add JUnit tests for it.  I created a simple bundle and wrote a test for it.  When I go to "Run As -> Junit Plug-in Test" I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bundle "org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime" not found. Possible causes include missing dependencies, too restrictive version ranges, or a non-matching required execution environment.
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.getClassLoader(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.readPluginArgs(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.init(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.CoreTestApplication.run(CoreTestApplication.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
An error has occurred. See the log file
```

I think it is probably because the PDE Junit Runner is not in my target.  My target has only

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="3.8.2.M20130131-0800"/>
<unit id="org.junit" version="0.0.0"/>
<unit id="org.hamcrest.core" version="0.0.0"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8"/>
</location>
```

I went looking for the PDE Runner and found it was at the releases site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`.  But if I create a new target from releases and updates sites, I get errors when I launch Equinox.

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.addon.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v20100831"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.standalone.feature.group" version="1.0.0.v20100831"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios"/>
</location>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="slicer" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="3.6.2.M20110210-1200"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6"/>
</location>
```

Comment: I suggest you to download a newer version of Eclipse, 3.6 is too much old.

Comment: thanks, but I am running on 3.8 Juno.  My target is 3.6 helios...

Comment: so if your target is 3.6 I suggest you to use it too because mix versions is a pain.

Comment: What errors do you get when launching Equinox? BTW, the features has been removed for Kepler. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404213